# How do I make a 'li a'-link clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styling

I have tried to make a webpage recently, just for practice, but I have one simple problem: I can't seem to make the whole 'button' around the 'li a' clickable, how do I do that?

This is the CSS I use for my menu:

```
#sideMenu {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#sideMenu:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}

#sideMenu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
}

#sideMenu li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#sideMenu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: overline;
}
```

Please ask if anything is unclear!

Comment: add `padding` for `a` not `li` and set it to `display:block`

Comment: add ul li a { display: block;}